# How do I use two mysql tables in one statement

Tags: php, mysql

So, I've put in a favourite images table, and I can't figure out how to get it working properly

Basically, this is the setup:

```
ImageFavs
FavID, UserID, ImgID

ImageList
ImgID, SiteID
```

I'd like it to select 20 or so images from the favourites table, but only ones that match the siteid in the image list table

This is the code I have at the moment, but it dawned on me it'd select 20 images from favourites, then only display them if the matching site was actually checked.

```
#select matching sites
for($i=0;$i<count($sites)-1;$i++){
    $siteinfo = explode("-",$sites[$i]);
    $siteid = $siteinfo[0];
    $sitegroup = $siteinfo[1];
    $selection[$siteid]="exists";
    if($i!=0){
        $sqlextra .= " OR ";
    }
    else{
        $sqlextra = "AND (";
    }
    $sqlextra .= "SiteID='".$siteid."'";
}
if(!empty($sqlextra)){
    $sqlextra .= ")";
}
else{
    $sqlextra = "AND SiteID='-1'";
}

#show favourites
if($_GET['f']==1){
    $sql="SELECT * FROM ImageFavs WHERE UserID='".$_SESSION['User_ID']."' AND Active = '1' ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 20";
    #(rand is just me being lazy, eventually I'll figure out how to separate it onto pages)
    $result = mysql_query($sql);
    $num = mysql_numrows($result);
    if($num>0){
        while ($row=mysql_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_BOTH)){
            if(empty($sqlextra2)){
                $sqlextra2 = " AND (";
            }
            else{
                $sqlextra2 .= " OR ";
            }
            $sqlextra2 .= "ImgID='".$row['ImgID']."'";
        }
        $sqlextra2 .= ")";
    }
}
#don't show favourites
if(empty($sqlextra2)){
    $sqlextra2 = " ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 20";
}
$sql="SELECT * FROM ImageList WHERE Valid='1' ".$sqlextra.$sqlextra2;
```

This output $sql from this seems like it could be so much neater though, an example of it is like this

```
SELECT * FROM ImageList WHERE Valid='1' AND (SiteID='6') AND (ImgID='5634' OR ImgID='8229' OR ImgID='9093' OR ImgID='5727' OR ImgID='7361' OR ImgID='5607' OR ImgID='7131' OR ImgID='5785' OR ImgID='7339' OR ImgID='5849' OR ImgID='7312' OR ImgID='5641' OR ImgID='8921' OR ImgID='7516' OR ImgID='7284' OR ImgID='5873' OR ImgID='8905' OR ImgID='7349' OR ImgID='7392' OR ImgID='8725')
```

Also, while I'm here, would there be a non resource heavy way to count the number of favourites for a user per website?

It's not for anything big, just messing around on a personal website to see what I can do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can `INNER JOIN` your two tables to get the results you want. `INNER` is used when you want results from both tables. It's best to use aliases to keep your tables straight.

```
SELECT l.*
FROM ImageFavs f
    INNER JOIN ImageList l ON f.ImgID = l.ImgID
WHERE l.SiteID = [your site ID]
    AND f.UserID='" . $_SESSION['User_ID'] . "' 
    AND f.Active = '1' 
    ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 20
```

To get a count by site you can use `GROUP BY`. I think this should get you that count

```
SELECT COUNT(f.ImgID)
FROM ImageFavs f
    INNER JOIN ImageList l ON f.ImgID = l.ImgID
WHERE f.UserID='" . $_SESSION['User_ID'] . "' 
    AND f.Active = '1' 
GROUP BY l.SiteID
```

Comment: Thanks man, you kinda made it easy to understand so I think I'll be able to do similar things from now on :)

Comment: Oh, one more thing, I tried to count the values and it gave an error, so I looked it up and found you need to use group by. I've tried 'GROUP BY l.ImgID, l.SiteID, f.FavID' and a few other combinations but it doesn't work, would you happen to know how to do this?

Comment: You want to know how many records overall or how many records returned?

Comment: Basically how many favourites the current user has for each website, it seems basically the same sql statement, aside from I can't get it to count the matching rows

Answer (score 1):

you want to use "JOIN"

```
SELECT * FROM ImageFavs LEFT JOIN ImageList ON ImageFavs.ImgID = ImageList.ImgID WHERE ImageList.SiteID = <your_site_id>
```

Comment: Thanks man, I replied to yours but someone else posted while I was writing and it added the reply to theirs aha, but yeah, it works fine, cheers, might select the other guy for best answer though as i learned a bit from it :)

Answer (score 1):

This works-

```
//Assuming $site_id contains the site ID/
$query = "select *.IF from ImageFavs as IF, ImageList as IL where IL.ImgId = IF.ImgId and IL.SiteId = $site_id LIMIT 20"
```

Comment: Ah thanks man, got it working, will this also be fairly light to run 7 times per page load for the counting part?

Comment: I think it should.It's simple and readable. Performance-wise, sub-query vs Joins in MySql seems to be the same for simple queries. Refer [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2577174/join-vs-sub-query)